# SQL query with column name obtained from another table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

trying to run the query

```
select * from customers, TablesList where TablesList.TableName+'ID' =
10 and tableslist.tableid= 123
```

where the column name obtained from another table. I get the following error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
the nvarchar value 'CustomersID' to data type int.
```

I know I can do something like `Select * from customers where customersID = 10`

But trying to create `CustomersID` column name dynamically from another table. The intent it to have `TablesList.TableName+'ID'` give me `CustomersID` string that I can use to equate to 10.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the whole query?. I mean, apart from the fact that you performing a cartesian product, I don't see the `CustomersID` column anywhere in your query

Comment: The intent it to have TablesList.TableName+'ID' give me CustomersID string that I can use to equate to 10

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the value for Tablelist.TableName is Customer so when you do + 'ID' it results in 'CustomerID'. 'CustomerID' is the VALUE that is returned and not the FIELD NAME that gets compared to 10.

Hence when sqlserver try to convert 'CustomerID' to 10 you get an error message telling you that it's not an integer Value.

As far as I know you cannot get a "field name" from a field value directly trough SQL, for that you'd need to create a stored proc or some kind of programming language to build the query dynamically

Answer (score 0):

`TablesList.TableName+'ID'` generates the string `'CustomersID'`. You get the error because your comparison is actually made like this:

```
'CustomersID' = 10 -- The comparison NVARCHAR = INT produces the error
```

What i think you're trying to achieve requires [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you have is that your where clause is checking if the value 'CustomerID' is equal to 10.  It isn't (and can't) use that string as a column name in that context.  You need to use [dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Dynamic SQL is where you build up a string which contains the SQL you ulitmately want to run.  So as an example, you could do something like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from customers where ' + (select top 1 TableName from TableList where tableId = 123) + 'ID = 10'

EXEC(@sql)
```

This sets the @sql variable to `select * from customers where customerID = 10` then runs that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use Concat:

select * from customers, TablesList where Concat('TablesList.TableName','ID') =
10 and tableslist.tableid= 123